# What is the C++ equivalent of Python's append method?

Tags: python, c++

Consider following code in python

```
li = [1,2,3]
li.append(4)
```

If you call li now, output will be:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

If you replicate code above using C++, what would it be?

Comment: What is the data structure that's being used behind the scenes?

Comment: @PeteBecker The only thing I know that in Python it is called list, I think it's quite similar to C++ arrays

Comment: @Nelver no, C++ arrays are **not** like Python lists.

Comment: The reason why we want to know the underlying data structure is that there are a few containers that supposedly do what that Python code is doing.  And when stating the data structure, use data structure terminology, such as linked list, hash table, whatever.  A generic term such as "Python list" doesn't really convey what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Congratulations on a question that uses two language tags correctly. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the C++11 equivalent would be this:

```
 #include <vector>

 int main(int argc, char ** argv)
 {
    std::vector<int> li = {1, 2, 3};
    li.push_back(4);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The only issue with this answer is that `std::list` and `std::deque` also fit.

Comment: IIRC, the Python implementation is closer (in terms of underlying data structure and big-O performance characteristics) to std::vector, though.

Answer (score -5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
using namespace std;


int tl[3]={1,2,3};
int tl2[4]={};
class apnddd {        
  public:          
    int* ol;  
    int* nl;  
    int it;      
    apnddd(int* l1, int* l2, int it) { 
      ol = l1;
      int sz = sizeof(l1)/sizeof(l1[0]);
      for(int i=0;i<sz+1;i++) {
          l2[i]=l1[i];
          }
         l2[sz+1]=it;
      nl = l2;
      
      
    }
};

int main()
{
    
  apnddd d1(tl, tl2, 4);
 
  int* tl=d1.nl;

  std::cout <<  d1.nl[3]<<tl[3];
  
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is too complicated